# Update value to the database without "Save" button

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to create `WPF` window using `MVVM` pattern. 
Now I have a problem to find out how update value, changed in the View, to the Database without using of the "Save" button, straight after value was changed and `ViewModel` was notified.

Control in the View

```
<ItemsControl>
    <Label Content="Order Date"/>
    <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding CreatedAt, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</ItemsControl>
```

ViewModel

```vb
Public Class ViewModelOrder
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Private _Order As ModelOrder

    '...
    Private _CreatedAt As DateTime
    Public Property CreatedAt As DateTime
    Get
        Return _CreatedAt
    End Get
    Set(value As DateTime)
        _CreatedAt = value
        Me.RaisePropertyChanged(Function() Me.CreatedAt)
    End Set
    '...
    Public Sub New(inOrder as ModelOrder)
        _Order = inOrder
        _CreatedAt = _Order.CreatedAt
    End Sub
    '...
End Class
```

Binding work fine, property `CreatedAt` updated after value was changed in the View.

I don't want to use Event handlers in the View "Code behind", because, as I understand MVVM pattern, ViewModel instance doesn't need to know about View.

Comment: why dont you just do so in the setter?

Comment: Ok, but how to find out that setter was called from the View, because same setter can be used by ViewModel to set value when get data from database?

Comment: Pass the value in the ctor when read from the db and  create the object

Comment: It is in constructor set by private variable. But when window opened setter of CreatedAt property was called three times. I checked CreatedAt proerty not using anywhere else.

Comment: So what if the setter got called 3 times.  If _CreatedAt == value then just return

Comment: in that case you can keep track of the current DB value in a separate variable and check to see if they are the same, if yes then dont update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do nothing if the value has not changed
I do C# so the VB may not be correct

```vb
Set(value As DateTime)
    If _CreatedAt <> value Then
        _CreatedAt = value
        ' update database
        Me.RaisePropertyChanged(Function() Me.CreatedAt)
    End If
End Set
```

Comment: Fabio your edit broke it  "_CreatedAt = value Then" is the "oposite of _CreatedAt = Then"